# How to update values in column which shows only once?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to update id values for only those items that appear only once in item column?

Table1

```
id | item | price
-------------
10 | pen  | 10  
20 | pen  | 10   
30 | pen  | 10
30 | copy | 10
10 | book | 10
10 | ball | 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set 
id = <whatever>
where
item in (select item from table group by item having count(*)=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
update t 
set t.id = <whatever>
where not exists (select 1 from table where item = t.item and id <> t.id);
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL; UPDATE does not table references.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Update Table1 set id = "val" 
group by item
having count(*) = 0
```

Comment: GROUP BY and then HAVING.

Comment: but I need to update only id that shows only once in ITEM COLUMN... so only those ids that corresponds to items "ball", "book", "copy" and "pen" should be ignored

Comment: sorry but i dont know this question is for sqllite,its works for sql server

Comment: This works, but if I want to update only items ids "10" and sticking to rules said before (items that appear only once)? I guess I have to use WHERE id=10 but I cannot get it to work together... WHERE and GROUP BY